# How can I implement a blocking wait in protractor (with jasmine) to call an async function, and fail the test immediately after the function returns?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine, protractor

During a protractor test running using `jasmine` test framework, I need to call an async function that returns a promise, blocking test execution until promise returns, and then check a condition and fail the protractor test immediately if condition is true, without executing further commands.

I've searched StackOverflow but didn't find a direct answer to my question that worked as I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 steps to this:

1. Explicitly create a promise, use browser.wait on it, and resolve the promise inside the async function if execution should continue
2. Create a promise.then, returning true so that browser.wait continues
3. Call "throw new Error" when you want to fail the current test immediately

```js
it('A unit test', function () {

     this.blockingWaitAndFail();

     thisFunctionShouldntRun();
});

this.blockingWaitAndFail = function () {

    // 1. Explicitly created promise
    // ------------
    var defer = protractor.promise.defer();
    // ------------

    this.functionThatReturnsPromise().then(function(returned){
        if (returned) {

            // 3. Throws error and stops test immediately
            // ------------
            throw new Error('Some error');
            // ------------

        } else {

            // 1. Resolves promise used in browser.wait
            // ------------
            defer.fulfill();
            // ------------

        }
    }, function(){
        throw new Error('Error calling function');
    });

    // 2. promise.then returning true
    defer.promise.then(function() {
        return true;
    }, function() {});

    // 1. browser.wait on created promise
    browser.wait(defer.promise, 10000, 'Timeout waiting for promise.');
}
```

Perhaps there's an easier way, or cleaner, but this is what I came up with. Comments on improvements are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
function myCheck()  {
 return myAsyncFunction().then(function () {
  return //condition
 );
}

expect(myCheck()).toEqual(false);
//Your test will fail at this point, if your condition returns true.

//rest of your code here. It will be run if the tests did not fail
```

Not sure it will work, but I am using something similar in my tests. The `expect` will resolve the promise of myCheck() and should give you result you're expecting.

Comment: I've tried this, but the first return doesn't return a boolean or a promise, as far as I can't tell. Not sure what exactly it returns, but it didn't work during my tests.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with AngularJS, Jasmine, or Protractor Promises so there maybe better more architecturally homogeneous solutions.

Having said that, standard Javascript ES6 Promises can be deployed such as: -

```
function wait(time) {
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
 var req = setTimeout(function(){resolve();}, time);
 });
 }

wait(5000).then(function(resp){alert('Finished waiting');},function(err){});
```

If your promises do not have the .THEN and .CATCH syntax/functionality you can use your asynchronous function to either resolve or reject the JS promise passed in via closure or global.

Your "if condition is true" logic whould go in the .THEN(function(returnValue){})

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which test framework you use, assuming you are using `mocha` or `jasmine`. From your question, it doesn't look like you want to wait for any condition, apart from waiting for the promise to be resolved. For such use case you don't need `browser.wait`. A simple solution like below should work based on what I gather from your question.

```
it('should immediately fail if the condition is returned', function(done) {
     this.functionThatReturnsPromise().then(function(returned) {
        if(returned) {
           done(throw new Error('Condition was not expected'));
        } else {
           done();
        }   
     });
});
```

Comment: I didn't want to use a promise syntax inside the "it". Rather, I wanted the function blockingWaitAndFail() to hold on itself. When doing this, I've tried using the done statement, but somehow after running blockingWaitAndFail() and failing, function thisFunctionShouldntRun ends up running anyway. And yes, running jasmine.

Comment: You can pass 'done' to 'functionThatReturnsPromise' and call done appropriately

Comment: I've tried that and couldn't make it work, not sure if I did anything wrong. It waited for the done, but somehow executed the next code line after functionThatReturnsPromise.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
somefunction().then(function(result){
   if(check condition){
      fail;
   }else{
      run tests;
   }
});
```